# I'm creating my own array class, using the vector class. How do I allow a user to assign each element individually?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a pretty simple array class, based on the vector class:

```
class myarray{
private:
    vector<double> data_;
    int size_; 
public:
/// Constructor that allocates the memory
myarray(const int& nx): size_(nx) {
  data_.resize(size_);
}
blah, blah, blah...
```

I want the user to be able to assign each element of myarray individually. For example, after declaring the object

```
myarray A(10);
```

I want the user to be able to do the following:

```
A(0) = 1; 
A(1) = 2;
```

and etc. How do I do this?

Comment: I'd suggest `A[0]` etc, but [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: What will be the additional functionality that your "array" will provide? Why will it be better than using `std::vector` directly?

Comment: If the new `myarray` has all of the same functionality as the `std::vector` and/or `std::array`, then this must be an exercise for homework.  Is this correct?

Comment: No. I am adding functionality to an existing array class that my coworkers are using. Eventually I want to interface this with python. Moreover, I have to use this because this class is being used by a whole sweet of other classes. So unfortunately, it's too late to use the standard vector class.

Answer (score 2):

Provide a couple of overloads for `operator()(size_t)`:

```
int& operator()(std::size_t i) { return data_[i]; }

const int& operator()(std::size_t i) const { return data_[i]; }
```

The first version allows you to read and write elements of a mutable instance of `myarray`. The second allows you to read elements of a `const` instance of `myarray` (or access via `const` reference or pointer-to-const.)

Note: strictly speaking, the correct type of the index would be `std::vector<double>::size_type`. This is usually the same as `std::size_t`, but may be different if a custom allocator is used.

Answer (score 1):

Provide an overloaded `operator()(int i)` function.

```
int operator()(int i ) { return data_[i]; }
```

Whether it is the right thing to do or not, it's your call.

If you want to be able to use:

```
A(0) = 5;
```

change the function to return a reference. In fact, have an overload of the `const` variety too.

```
int& operator()(int i ) { return data_[i]; }
int const& operator()(int i ) const { return data_[i]; }
```

Comment: THis doesn't seem to allow me to assign elements, like A(3) = 5.0;